# How do I only reverse proxy php files with nginx?

Tags: nginx, php, proxy, apache2

Currently I have the following in my nginx config file:

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {

    listen 443;
    server_name envy.zone;

    ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/cert.key;
    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/cloudflare.crt;
    ssl_verify_client on;

   location /
{

      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      proxy_pass          https://localhost:8081;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;
      proxy_redirect      http://localhost:8080 https://envy.zone;
    }
  }
```

With my current configuration nginx is configured to send every single http and https request to apache2. I only want php files to be reverse proxied to apache2 and leave the request of requests to nginx (for example *.png can be handled by nginx fine). How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

At first, not sure why you need apache behind nginx.

Now, **if you don't do rewrites in Apache which hide the PHP extension**, just modify your location block like this:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    proxy_set_header       Host $host;
    proxy_set_header       X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header       X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    X-Forwarded-For        $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_pass             https://localhost:8081;
    proxy_read_timeout     90;
    proxy_redirect         http://localhost:8080 https://envy.zone;
}
```

And you should be good to go.